# "A Task Scheduler" is Required when using Spring Integration with MQTT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, mqtt

I have a project where I am using Spring Integration where I am connecting to a broker and then publish-subscribe the messages issued to the broker.

When using @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan and @Configuration the application runs fine that is using @SpringBootApplication as a whole. But I don't want to use @EnableAutoConfiguration, this is just a POC project to be integrated into a bigger chunk project. Where, if @EnableAutoConfiguration is used may cause issues for other components which are not needed.

So, how can I resolve this issue?

This is just an excerpt from the project and when done should run normally:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class TestMQTTApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestMQTTApp.class,args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter inbound() {
        String clientId = "uuid-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("tcp://localhost:1883", clientId, "topic1"   );
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        return adapter;
    }
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory =
                new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Error is as follows:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inbound'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A 'taskScheduler' is required
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) ~[spring-context-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:350) ~[spring-context-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-context-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) ~[spring-context-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.harman.TestSpring.main(TestSpring.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A 'taskScheduler' is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.doStart(MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:145) ~[spring-integration-mqtt-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:117) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

I am having trouble scanning the packages for the task scheduler although nowhere in the code have I mentioned this.

**Additional Information for POM:**

- Spring Boot - 1.5.1.RELEASE
- Spring Framework Version - 4.3.20.RELEASE
- Spring Integration - 4.3.20.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `@EnableIntegration`. That one adds a broader Spring Integration infrastructure , included a required `TaskScheduler`. See docs foer more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#configuration-enable-integration

Comment: Thanks @Artem that does solve the issue. We need to include all beans included in that scope and it certainly finds taskScheduler as well. This is the case where you could find with the help of Annotation based class, but what about the case when we don't know the annotation and still want spring to recognize the beans? Is there a way?

Comment: Well, the annotation processor does the hard job for you to bring many beans into an application context. It would be better to learn the tool you use. Spring Boot does a heavy lifting with its auto-configuration , but without it we have to consult with the target libraries we are using in our code